# Best algorithm to compute the mean?

Tags: algorithms

Given a finite memory (say N "slots") and a stream of numbers M (represented as floating point numbers) where (M > N) is there a provable best algorithm in the sense that it outputs the mean of the stream closest to the mathematical mean?

Comment: You can find the exact mean in time $O(M)$ by using $2$ memory slots, one for the current sum and one for the number of items seen. What I am missing?

Comment: @lhf with floating point numbers, you get accumulated rounding errors. The question asks for the number closest to the mean, given the memory limitations. Using more than two slots might give a result closer to the actual mean.

Comment: One good way to avoid too much accumulated rounding error when summing numbers is to sort them in decreasing order. But that can't be done in one pass with limited memory. You may want to try [Kahan summation algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm). See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394174/how-best-to-sum-up-lots-of-floating-point-numbers.